# Calendar month, week, day how to control?

Tags: 2013, calendar

I'm using the calendar in 2013. If I click a date while in month view the calendar changes to day view. But there is no apparent way to go back to month view.

I found several posts online about using the query string **?CalendarPeriod=month** to set the view. However when I click the date there is no querystring and setting a querystring would cause a page load and give a history state. When I try the back button it doesn't take me to the previous view just the previous screen I was on.

I know there are some buttons in the ribbon, but because I (and my users) didn't use the ribbon to change the view it isn't natural to think of using the ribbon to undo it.

Is there a way to add on the calendar itself a button that takes the user back to the previous view without causing a browser reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're in the day view, the little calendar on top of the left navigation also changes from year view to month view. You can then just click the month on top of that little calendar to go back to the month view.

Answer (score 0):

If the default scope for the view is month then just refreshing the page will change the view back to the month view.